# Problem loading pickle files as pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, load, pickle

I am trying to load a .dat file as a dataframe using:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

file_to_read = open(load_path_SQTN_f+str(identifier[which_one])+"_with_SQTN_final.dat", "rb") # sto trito bale 2 opws einai twra
SQTN = pickle.load(file_to_read)
file_to_read.close()
```

I get the following error.

```
Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\_libs\\internals.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'>
```

I tried updating pandas to the latest version with:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas --user
```

I have also tried loading the .pkl file using

```
SQTN = pd.read_pickle(load_path_SQTN_f+str(identifier[which_one])+"_with_SQTN_final.dat")
```

Which once again is giving me the same error.

Note that I can load other .dat files on the same anaconda env without a problem.

Could it be because the underlying pickle for pandas is not compatible with the pickle I used to dump? If so how could I fix the issue?

Comment: "I get the following error." post the *full error message including the stack trace*

Comment: "Could it be because the underlying pickle for pandas is not compatible with the pickle I used to dump? " You aren't using "pickle for pandas". `pickle` is a part of the standard library. If I had to guess, it looks like you are trying to unpickle a dataframe (or other `pandas` object) with a different version of pandas that the object was originally created with.

Comment: Note, I found that duplicate by simply googling the error message.

Comment: Was the pickle file created with `pandas` or otherwise? And with the same `pandas` version you are using?

Comment: @René It was created using pandas. I didnt update pandas and was able to load this particular file a few days ago.